# Inequality of $(|a|^{\ell-2}a- |b|^{\ell-2}b\Big)(a-b) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Letting $\epsilon\geq0$ be small, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\ell >1$. 
Is the following inquality
$$\tag{E}\label{E} \Big((\sqrt{\epsilon^2+|a|^2})^{\ell-2}a- (\sqrt{\epsilon^2+|b|^2})^{\ell-2}b\Big)(a-b)\geq 0, $$
true?

If $\epsilon=0$, \eqref{E} becomes 
$$(|a|^{\ell-2}a- |b|^{\ell-2}b\Big)(a-b)\geq 0, $$
which is true by using the following inequalities: 
\begin{align}
\left(|a|^{\ell-2}a-|b|^{\ell-2}b\right)\cdot (a-b)\geq 2^{-\ell}|a-b|^2,&\quad  \ell\geq 2,\\
\left(|a|^{\ell-2}a-|b|^{\ell-2}b\right)\cdot (a-b)\geq (\ell-1)|a-b|^2\left(|a|+|b|\right)^{\ell-2}  ,&\quad  1<\ell \leq 2.
\end{align}
 $a\cdot b$ denotes the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Can any one know if \eqref{E} is true or not?

**Here my try for the answer:**
Letting $\epsilon$ small. Denoting by $f$ the function defined as $$f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{\ell}(\epsilon^2+|\mathbf{x}|^2)^{\ell/2}.$$
 $f$ is convexe in $\mathbf{x}$. Then, by the convexity proprity we have 
$$(f'(\mathbf{x})-f'(\mathbf{y}))\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})\geq c\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2.$$
Then \eqref{E} holds. I don't know there is a mistake or not.

Comment: Is the product taken to be the ordinary inner product?

Comment: Yes, $a.b$ denotes the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^N$.